# Laravel - php Identifying multiple check in / check out in attendance

Tags: php, laravel, checkout, checkin

We are developing a simple attendance system based on Laravel Framework. We are new to Laravel framework. 
We use the basic auth system of Laravel. The user can check in / check out using the system. While doing,the user is supposed to take a photo of their own and we also get the location details from browser.

For attendance, we have the following schema:
id (primary Key) (int)
userid (int) (foreign key to id of the user table)
status (boolean) ( 0 - out / 1 - in)
attendancedatetime (datetime)
gpslat (float)
gpslon (float)
photourl (varchar)

Now we wish to avoid check-in/check-out by an user within few minutes (say for example within 10 minutes).

Also, we wish to avoid multiple check-in or multiple check-out by the same user at a time.

Is it possible to do this in Laravel Controller?

Will [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88424/laravel-time-punching-database-structure) provide any solution to our problem?

Comment: Can you give some examples of multiple check-in, check-out and it's use cases?

Comment: for example the user may have checked in at 9.00 a.m. the system should consider the next one as check out which should be considered only after some **x** minutes say 30 minutes. Also, within a day the same user 'check out ' and 'check in' of lunch should also need to be noted (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly Find out last checked details by

```
select max(time(attendancedatetime)) as last_checked_time
From<TableName>
WHERE userid=<USERID> and DATE(attendancedatetime)=<Current Date>
```

after that in Laravel,  compare this returned last_checked_time with current time. If it  is less then 30 minutes  return false else run your insert statement!